# .Net Library for parsing source code files?

Tags: .net, parsing

Does anyone know of a good .NET library that allows me to parse source code files, but not only .NET source code files (like java, perl, ruby, etc)?

I need programmatic access to the contents of various source code files (e.g. class/method /parameter names, types, etc.).

Has anyone come across something like this? I know within .NET it is reasonably possible and there are some libraries out there, but I need that to be abstracted to more types of programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options:

1. You could pick a parsing framework that has a lot of existing grammars (like [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) or newer ones like [Irony](http://www.codeplex.com/irony)) and use that. This will offer the most fidelity.
2. If you could stick to just .NET languages, you could use the [Common Compiler Infrastructure tools](http://cciast.codeplex.com/) to read the data from a compiled file.
3. You could do a heuristic based approach like the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) component uses.
4. You could piggy-back off existing tools that offer pluggable syntax highlighting files like VIM. You'd have to create or find a parser that understood those files though.

Comment: Irony looks way more comfortable to me.. gonna go with that for a deeper evaluation.. thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but you might consider looking at this: [Discovering Code with the Code Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz746te4(vs.71).aspx)

Comment: hi, the link is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Would [Antlr](http://sharptoolbox.com/tools/antlr) meet your needs?

Comment: Well Antlr does seem nice, but like a whole new world to explore / learn and get used to. I am more or less looking for a 'finished' product tailored for specific languages (e.g. something like http://www.metaspec.net for c#, but also for other languages)...

Answer (score 0):

A tool designed to parse source code, build corresponding compiler data structures (trees, etc.), let you navigate/manipulate those structures, and regenerate valid source code (including comments!) is the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

It has a full C# 4.0 front end.

It doesn't provide access to those structures from C#; rather, it provides its own environment for coding program analysis and transformations, with a huge amount of support for doing this relatively easily (and considerably easier than doing in pure C#).